# R .csv not read in correctly because there are double quotes in the text

Tags: r, regex, notepad++

I have a .csv file that contains all text fields. However, some of the text fields contain an unescaped double quote character, eg:

```
"ID","Text","Optional text","Date" 
"1","Today is going to be a good day","","2013-02-03"
"2","And I am inspired by the quote "every dog must have it's day"","Hi","2013-01-01"
"3","Did not the bard say All the World's a stage" this quote is so true","Terrible","2013-05-05"
```

Lines 1 and 2 are fine but 3 doesn't read in correctly. At the moment I am manually going through the file in Notepad++ to try and remove such quotes. Ideally I'd like R to be able to handle this but I think that the unescaped nature of the unmatched double quote makes such an expectation unreasonable.

In Notepad++ I am trying to build a regular expression to identify double quotes that are not preceded or succeeded by a comma. The logic is that a valid double quote will be at the start or end of a field and this is signified by an adjacent comma. This might help to identify the majority of my cases, which I can then deal with.

Just to say that I have about 3.4 million records and about 0.1% appear to be problematic.

EDIT:
fread from data.table has been suggested as an alternative, but use of fread is even less successful:

```
1: In fread(paste(infilename, "1", ".csv", sep = "")) :
  Stopped early on line 21. Expected 18 fields but found 9. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line
```

Nether of the suggested options works. I think this is because the "Text" field can also contain CRLF characters. The read.csv appears to just ignore these (good) whilst fread takes exception. Sorry that I can not make the actual text available, but here is some more comprehensive test data, that has both the unmatched double quote (read.csv has issues with) and CRLF (fread has issues with).

```
"ID","Text","Optional text","Date" 
"1","Today is going to be a good day","","2013-02-03"
"2","And I am inspired by the quote "every dog must have it's day"","Hi","2013-01-01"
"3","An issue with this line is that it contains a CRLF here 
which is not usual.","Again an unusual CRLF
is present in these data","2013-02-02"
"4","Did not the bard say All the World's a stage" this quote is so true","Terrible","2013-05-05"
```

Help with the regex in Notepad++ would be great.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible and better understandible by 1) sharing a dput of (part of) your data? 2) Telling us what function you used to read the data, 3) telling us what the issue is with this?

Comment: Would this one work with np++? Search for [`(?:^\h*"|","|"\h*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|"`](https://regex101.com/r/I02FJs/1/) and replace with `\\"`

Comment: I can not read the problematic data into R so I can not dput() anything?

Comment: np++ reports (?:^\h*"|","|"\h*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|" as an Invalid Regular Expression.

Comment: @StephenClark What version of np++? I use v7.7 and it works.

Comment: v7.5.4 here. I will request an upgrade to v7.7. Thanks.

Comment: Can you guarantee that none of the quoted text contains a comma? Then you could simply import with `quote = ""` and remove double quotes at start and end of each character string as a post-processing step. And I hope you pay a visit to whoever collected the data and educate them regarding your issues.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one option could be to use a conditional replacement in notepad++.

You could find all the strings that start with a double quote which start with a comma or at the start of the string.

Then match not a double quote until you encounter the next double quote where a comma follows or the end of the string. These are the lines white are ok, so for the alternation part that you want to capture and replace match a double quote not between comma's.

**Find what:**

```
(?:^|,)"[^"\n]*"(?=$|,)|(?<!,)(")(?!,)
```

**Replace with:**

A conditional replacement. If group 1, then replace with empty, else replace with the match.

```
(?{1}:$0)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v5Pwp7/1)

**Explanation**

- `(?:^|,)` Match either a comma or assert the start of the string
- `"[^"\n]*"` Match the double quotes when there is no double quote in between
- `(?=$|,)` Assert what is on the right is either the end of the string or a comma
- `|` OR
- `(?<!,)(")(?!,)`Capture a double quote in group1 while asserting what is on the left and on the right is not a comma

Comment: What I want is to find a double qoute that does not have a comma to its left or right. ie find the double quotes in `asdf asdf" asdf" jjkn k` but not here `,"`, here `",` or here `,"",`

Comment: The web tools looks good. How to change the regex so that it does not pick up double quotes at the start and end of the line? Thank . https://regex101.com/r/QdFJwm/3

Comment: @StephenClark You might use `(?<!^)(?<!,)["“](?!(?:,| *$))` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QdFJwm/4)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work rather well with `data.table::fread`:

```
fread("E:/temp/test.txt")
#   ID                                                                 Text Optional text     "Date"
#1:  1                                      Today is going to be a good day               2013-02-03
#2:  2        And I am inspired by the quote "every dog must have it's day"            Hi 2013-01-01
#3:  3 Did not the bard say "All the World's a stage" this quote is so true      Terrible 2013-05-05
#Warning message:
#In fread("E:/temp/test.txt") :
#  Found and resolved improper quoting in first 100 rows. If the fields are not quoted (e.g. field separator does not appear within any field), try quote="" to avoid this warning.
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use fread but there were other issues with the file that mean fread was even less successful (I will add these to the original post above). At the moment my best option is to use {read.csv} but try and clean up some of the double quote issues.